# Error message in bind key event

Tags: python, tkinter

I am struggling to bind a left arrow press with a printed message. Any thoughts? I've searched this site and seem to be following the same instructions others have used, but it's still not working! I am very new to Python (and coding in general) and would really appreciate the help!

The error message:

```
NameError: name 'onArrowKey' is not defined
```

Relevant code:

```
from Tkinter import*

class FullScreenApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
        master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom
    def onArrowKey(self,event): 
        print 'Got arrow key press'


root=Tk()
root.bind('<Left>', onArrowKey)
root.config(background="black")
root.title("Who buzzed in first?")
app=FullScreenApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should move the problematic statement (`root.bind('<Left>', onArrowKey)`) in the `__init__` of your class :

like this :

```
master.bind('<Left>', self.onArrowKey)
```

Comment: I used this solution and got it fixed! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In the context you're writing in, `onArrowKey` has no definition. Move the `def onArrowKey` out of the `FullScreenApp` class, so that the context is right, or call `app.onArrowKey` instead of `onArrowKey` (after assigning app).